# how to to organize my data with sqlite using primary key and get data

Tags: python, sqlite, primary-key

I would like to have a database from which I can extract in python data according to date and positions.

Indeed, I have a main table like this:

```
T0154       45.7571 10.9999 165 
T0405       45.7861 11.0238 170 
T0153       45.7392 11.0655 692     
T0146       45.9684 11.0912 182
```

where the first line represents station ID, the 2nd, 3rd, 4th the x,y,z coordinate. I have also other tables which represent precipitation and temperature data for each station {T0154,T0405, T0153, T0146}. I have two tables for each station with precipitations and temperatures. One of them looks like (for example station T0405):

```
1991-07-13 12:00:00 1.8 5.0
1991-07-13 13:00:00 8.6 8.0
1991-07-13 14:00:00     
1991-07-13 15:00:00     
1991-07-13 16:00:00     
1991-07-13 17:00:00     
1991-07-13 18:00:00     
1991-07-13 19:00:00     
1991-07-13 20:00:00     
1991-07-13 21:00:00 0.0 1.0
1991-07-13 22:00:00
```

what do you think? Is it feasible?
Thanks

Comment: I misundetrstood. You tagged your question with `python`, which means, you want to parse CSV data (textfile), then fill it into table? If so, you need to split your task to 2 subtasks - 1) parse CSV file 2) save parsed data into database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there isn't a fantastic amount of data *(8760 (not many) rows is 1 station's data for a year)* then having a table per reading per station is probably inefficient and would complicate collating data on a coordinate basis.

I'd suggest a single table for all readings from all stations along the lines of :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main (StationId TEXT PRIMARY KEY, x REAL, y REAL, z REAL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log (timestamp TEXT, stationid_reference TEXT REFERENCES main(StationId), temperature REAL, precipitation REAL , PRIMARY KEY (timestamp,stationid_reference));
```

Perhaps consider the following example :-

```
/* Clean up testing environments just in case */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main;

/* Create the two tables */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main (StationId TEXT PRIMARY KEY, x REAL, y REAL, z REAL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log (
    timestamp TEXT, 
    stationid_reference TEXT REFERENCES main(StationId), /* FOREIGN KEY TO REFERENCE THE Station */
    temperature REAL, 
    precipitation REAL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (timestamp,stationid_reference) /* combination of timestamp and stationid must be unique */
);

/* Add the stations */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO main VALUES 
        ('T0154',45.7571,10.9999,165),
        ('T0405',45.7861,11.0238,170),
      ('T0153',45.7392,11.0655,692),
        ('T0146',45.9684,11.0912,182)
;

/* Add Some test readings */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO log VALUES
  ('1991-07-13 12:00:00','T0405',1.8,5.0),
    ('1991-07-13 13:00:00','T0405',8.6,8.0),
    ('1991-07-13 14:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 15:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 16:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 17:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 18:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 19:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 21:00:00','T0405',0.0,1.0),
    ('1991-07-13 22:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 23:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    ('1991-07-14 24:00:00','T0405',null,null),
    
    ('1991-07-13 12:00:00','T0154',1.8,5.0),
    ('1991-07-13 13:00:00','T0154',8.6,8.0),
    ('1991-07-13 14:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 15:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 16:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 17:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 18:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 19:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 21:00:00','T0154',0.0,1.0),
    ('1991-07-13 22:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 23:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    ('1991-07-14 24:00:00','T0154',null,null),
    
    
    ('1991-07-13 12:00:00','T0153',2.8,5.0),
    ('1991-07-13 13:00:00','T0146',8.6,8.0),
    ('1991-07-13 14:00:00','T0153',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 15:00:00','T0146',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 16:00:00','T0153',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 17:00:00','T0146',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 18:00:00','T0153',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 19:00:00','T0146',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 21:00:00','T0153',0.0,1.0),
    ('1991-07-13 12:00:00','T0146',null,null),
    ('1991-07-13 23:00:00','T0153',null,null),
    ('1991-07-14 24:00:00','T0146',null,null)
    
;

/* Get the average readings per day per station */
SELECT 
    stationid, x,y,z, date(timestamp),
    coalesce(avg(temperature),0) AS daily_average_temp, 
    coalesce(avg(precipitation),0) AS daily_average_precipitation
    
FROM main JOIN log ON stationid_reference = stationid
/* WHERE y > 11.0 <<<< WHERE CLAUSE COMMENTED OUT*/
GROUP BY stationid,date(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp, date(timestamp);

/* Get the average readings per day per station but only those who's y coord is greater than 11.0 */
/* i.e. same as previous result BUT without station T0154 */
SELECT 
    stationid, x,y,z,date(timestamp),
    coalesce(avg(temperature),0) AS daily_average_temp, 
    coalesce(avg(precipitation),0) AS daily_average_precipitation
    
FROM main JOIN log ON stationid_reference = stationid
WHERE y > 11.0
GROUP BY stationid,date(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp, date(timestamp);
```

Results :-

### First Query (all)

[image]

### 2nd Query (selective by coord)

[image]

- To do either of the above with seperate tables would either require a more complex query or for the SQL to be built programtically.

## Speed Test

If you consider the following adaptation of the above which inserts **350400** rows. i.e. 24 rows per day, for 365 days a year for 10 years for 4 stations, with randomly generated temp and precipitaions values, as per :-

```
/* Clean up testing environments just in case */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main;

/* Create the two tables */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, StationId TEXT UNIQUE, x REAL, y REAL, z REAL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS   log (
    timestamp TEXT, 
    stationid_reference INTEGER REFERENCES main(id), /* FOREIGN KEY TO REFERENCE THE Station */
    temperature REAL, 
    precipitation REAL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (timestamp,stationid_reference)/* combination of timestamp and stationid must be unique */
);

/* Add the stations */
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO main (stationid,x,y,z) VALUES 
        ('T0154',45.7571,10.9999,165),
        ('T0405',45.7861,11.0238,170),
      ('T0153',45.7392,11.0655,692),
        ('T0146',45.9684,11.0912,182)
;

/* ADD 10 years of data for each station with randomly generated readings */
WITH cte(cnt,ts,sid,t,p) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
          1,
            '1971-01-01 00:00:00',
            1,  
            (ABS(random()) % 3000) / 99.35
            , ABS(random()) % 25 / 99.35
            AS b
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            cnt + 1,
            datetime('1971-01-01 00:00:00','+'||(cnt / 96)||' days','+'||((cnt / 4) % 24)||' hours'), 
            ((cnt % 4) +1), 
            (ABS(random()) % 3000) / 99.35
            , ABS(random()) % 25 / 99.35
            FROM cte AS d
            LIMIT 8760 * 4 * 10
    )
-- SELECT * FROM cte;
INSERT INTO log SELECT ts,sid,t,p FROM cte;
;


SELECT 
    stationid, x,y,z, date(timestamp),
    coalesce(avg(temperature),0) AS daily_average_temp, 
    coalesce(avg(precipitation),0) AS daily_average_precipitation
FROM main JOIN log ON stationid_reference = main.id
/* WHERE y > 11.0 <<<< WHERE CLAUSE COMMENTED OUT*/
GROUP BY stationid,date(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp, date(timestamp);

/* Get the average readings per day per station but only those who's y coord is greater than 11.0 */
/* i.e. same as previous result BUT without station T0154 */
SELECT 
    stationid, x,y,z, date(timestamp),
    coalesce(avg(temperature),0) AS daily_average_temp, 
    coalesce(avg(precipitation),0) AS daily_average_precipitation
FROM main JOIN log ON stationid_reference = main.id
WHERE y > 11.0
GROUP BY stationid,date(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp, date(timestamp);


/* Clean up testing environments just in case */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main;
```

- Note that an alias of the rowid has been used for the refrence (foreign key) from the log to the station table (as this may prove to be more efficient)

Then everything is done in about 7 seconds (this includes the very costly deletion of the rows when dropping the tables to cleanup the environment about 2.5 seconds, the insert took 1.25 seconds)

The two queries took together took under 1 second as per :-

```
SELECT 
    stationid, x,y,z, date(timestamp),
    coalesce(avg(temperature),0) AS daily_average_temp, 
    coalesce(avg(precipitation),0) AS daily_average_precipitation
FROM main JOIN log ON stationid_reference = main.id
/* WHERE y > 11.0 <<<< WHERE CLAUSE COMMENTED OUT*/
GROUP BY stationid,date(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp, date(timestamp)
> OK
> Time: 0.478s


/* Get the average readings per day per station but only those who's y coord is greater than 11.0 */
/* i.e. same as previous result BUT without station T0154 */
SELECT 
    stationid, x,y,z, date(timestamp),
    coalesce(avg(temperature),0) AS daily_average_temp, 
    coalesce(avg(precipitation),0) AS daily_average_precipitation
FROM main JOIN log ON stationid_reference = main.id
WHERE y > 11.0
GROUP BY stationid,date(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp, date(timestamp)
> OK
> Time: 0.33s
```

- Obviously timings would depend upon the machine on which it is run.
- The first query ouput 14600 rows (4 stations with 1 row per day for 10 years i.e. 4 * 3650)
- The second query output 10950 rows (i.e. 3 stations as T0154 is excluded).

An example of the results from the first query :-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to study a lot in order to understand your technical details. Moving to my amount of data. I have many and many data. For example for the station T0154 i have 68587 data. One data every 5min. I could parse them in order to have hourly but the amount is still big.